# Fixed ip in WiFi adapter via netplan

Tags: wireless, netplan

I want to establish a fixed ip to my WiFi adapter in Ubuntu 20.04 from netplan but I always get an error "No access points defined" when I run "netplan try".
Is it possible to do this from netplan?

---

Finally I managed to do it. This is my netplan file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.212.100/24
      access-points:
        wifiName:
          password: wifiPassword
```

Comment: Are you defining an access point? Including your complete YAML in the question above would help us to understand.

Comment: I try to do several things but that will go into another more detailed query. For now I am only trying to be able to assign a fixed IP when connecting to a Wi-Fi network from netplan. Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Your netplan file says the renderer is NetworkManager. If you are running NM, that is the place to set  a static IP address, not netplan. Please clarify. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. It works with that file.

Comment: Glad it's working. You're all set.